# Segmentation Fault in Ubuntu

Tags: c

I keep getting Segmentation Fault Error when provided with the following arguments in Ubuntu

```
gcc program.c
./a.out $gjdvc1A
```

In the following code

```
# include <stdio.h>
 int lcount(char str[])
 { int i=0;
     while(str[i]!='\0')
     {
         i++;
     }
     if (i<5||i>15)
        printf("0");
     else
        printf("1");
 }
main(int argc , char *argv[])

{


    lcount( argv[1]);


}
```

Can any body help me and tell that why is this happening

Comment: What should this program do? Do not try to fool us, as I don't think this is the actual code. It does not compile, it does not have a semicolon in the function call. You have just handwritten the code. Copy paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the value of an environment variable $gjdvc1A as an argument. And your program does not have any argument checking, it will always crash when the value for the environment variable is not set

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make some fixes to compile the program.

```
# include <stdio.h>
int lcount(char str[]) {
  int i=0;
  while(str[i]!='\0')
  {
    i++;
  }
  if (i<5||i>15)
    printf("0");
  else
   printf("1");
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
  lcount( argv[1]);
}
```

Then, the problem is not in your code (even if it should be heavily improved!). The problem is that you are calling it with an empty argument because `$gjdvc1A` is evaluated as an empty variable by the shell, and since you do not have any safety check in your code it will result in a segmentation fault.

**Solution**

- Wrap program arguments in single quotes if you don't want them to be evaluated by the shell
- Always perform safety check on program arguments!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about this problem very well, but I think I got the answer.

Basically, `argv[]` is an array hat holds your command line parameters, `argv[1]` is the first one (other than the command representation itself in `argv[0]`, of course).

Well, when executing the program, when you pass the argument `$gjdvc1A`, the shell is evaluating it as an empty variable because of the symbol `$`.

Also, your program has a mistake:

Change `lcount( argv[1])` to `lcount( argv[1]);`

To pass an argument with `$` in the front, just put a `\` which escapes the character.

This program you have written is bad, and you should do error checking, and of course, safety checks on arguments.

To make this program be better, use `int main` and put a `return 0` at the end of the `main`.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument started with `$` symbol in bash, bash treats it as a variable and try to get the value of that variable before passing that to the program. So when you are running `./a.out $gjdvc1A` bash actually looks for variable `gjdvc1A` and since there is no variable with that name it passes nothing as `argv[1]`. In other words this is equivalent to running `./a.out` without any argument. So when you try to access `str[0]` inside `lcount` function, you are trying to access a garbage address and thus getting the segmentation fault.

To solve the issue you need to escape `$` or use quote while calling to tell bash not to treat it as a variable.

```
./a.out \$gjdvc1A
```

or

```
./a.out '$gjdvc1A'
```

In addition to this issue there are other problems too:

- You should use `int` as return type of `main` and call `return 0;` at end of main.
- There is a missing semicolon at line `lcount( argv[1])`.